# Prevent duplication form entry

Tags: javascript, php, html

i need to prevent duplicate data entry for form data. 
Feature is: Form-contains section and number of students. we can add multiple sections. and i need to prevent duplicate section name.
Pls look into the code,

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mysql","inventory");
$number = count($_REQUEST["name"]);

if($number > 0)
{
    for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
    {
        if(trim($_REQUEST["name"][$i]) != '')
        {

            $id = $_REQUEST['idref'];
            $c = $_REQUEST["clas"];
            $s = $_REQUEST["name"][$i];
            $k = $_REQUEST["k"][$i];
            $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM budget WHERE section='".$s."'");
                if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
                    {
                        echo "already exists";
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO budget(sid,k,section,stu) VALUES('$id','$c','$k','$s')";
                        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                    }
        }
    }   
}
else
{echo "Enter section";

}
```

Comment: what is the problem now? could write type of sid field in database?

Comment: why you have  ` in  if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)` this

Comment: If you have a primary key, you could just use insert ignore...

Comment: @RafailAkhmetshin This code is to enter the form data into table. HTML page has 5 forms. and in each form there is an input element for adding section name. ie name. by clicking on add button js will create one more section input element. now what i need is, this section name should be unique. if user enters duplicate section name it should pop up an msg. Here in code HTML - attribute name is "name". name refers to section and i'm storing in variable s.

Comment: could you describe what will be assumed as "duplicate entry"? for example "same section, same stu", could add some details on table colmns, what are primary and etc?

Comment: @RafailAkhmetshin Input fields- 1.section text box(ie $s) 2.count text box(ie $k). Here i have add button. by clicking on add button js function will create one more section and count text boxes. Assume i need to add 3 sections. ie.. Section-A, count-100. Section-B, Count-200. Section-C, count-150. Here if user enters a duplicate section alphabet EX- Section-A, Count-100, Section-A(again A section name duplicate) count-200 now it should display that section name is duplicate.